# Issue with finding installed Steam games on Mint

Tags: linux-mint, steam

I'm on Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon, Linux kernel version 4.15.0-20-generic.

I've installed the Flathub version Steam from the Software Manager because it's the only version that works for me.  When I install games, they install and boot perfectly fine; however, when I go to where Steam claims to have installed them (`~/.local/Steam/steamapps`), none of them are actually there.

It doesn't end here either, when playing a game that allows me to open a file (RPG Maker MV for example), it shows me a completely different, perhaps virtual, file system.  When I navigate to the steamapps/common folder on this in-game file explorer, it shows me all of the games I've installed on Steam, as opposed to when I open the same directory from the regular file explorer and the terminal.

Does Steam install games on a virtual file system? If so, where is this file system? I'd like to access the files for RPG Maker projects but it would seem like they don't actually exist.  The strangest part is that the Resource Manager even says that RPG Maker is being run from the steamapps directory, even though it's not there.

I've tried looking up whether or not Proton has a virtual file system where it stores Steam games but it seems like Proton only does that for Windows games (since it's a fork of WINE, I'd assume it stores Windows files in a Windows FS).  RPG Maker MV is not a Windows game and should, in theory, be stored on my main partition in the steamapps folder, but it doesn't appear to be there; I'm completely stumped as to why.

Comment: Software run in containers, like flathub, are generally run with their own virtual filesystem that is isolated from the system's main filesystem.   Most container systems have some method of allowing shared storage.  In flathub's case, it looks as if it does that with a `~/.var` subdirectory.  See https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/wiki/Filesystem for details.  That's pretty much all I know about flathub, so I can't help any further.

Comment: As @cas mentioned (~/.var), check under `~/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam`.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Thank you, issue solved.